# Do colour-blind people see through certain kinds of camouflage?

Tags: biology, war, colors

I found this claim in *Unweaving the Rainbow* by Richard Dawkins. This is the Google Books [link to the relevant page](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=ZudTchiioUoC&q=camouflage#v=snippet&q=camouflage&f=false).

> Nobody knows whether or how this benefits them, but it may be
>   suggestive that bomber crews in the Second World War liked to include
>   at least one colour-blind member, who could penetrate certain kinds of
>   camouflage on the ground.

Is there any research to back this?

Comment: [The Straight Dope](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/3037/is-colorblindness-an-evolutionary-advantage) has an article on this, with references.

Comment: Yes, I know that an anecdote is not research.  But my colourblind grandfather was absolutely invaluable during World War Two, due to his ability to see enemy soldiers in camouflage.

Comment: I have a certain amount of color impairment but I am not color blind by any means.  I think I was like 12 or 13 before I understood about nature programs talking about the lion "hiding" in the grass--because he stuck out like a sore thumb to me.  Natural camouflage tends to work very poorly on me.

Comment: I can't address color-**blind**, but I have moderate deuteranopia (red/green weakness) and growing up it took me a long time to understand camouflage because much of it doesn't work on me. The nature programs would refer to the lion hiding in the grass--what do you mean, hiding, that lion is as plain as day!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It would seem to be correct. The following is an extract the [Nature Journal's archive](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v146/n3694/abs/146226a0.html):

> For example, in a building camouflaged with large irregular patches of
>   colour, the actual outline of the building may be lost in the jumble
>   of these patterns. But the colour-blind person may be scarcely
>   conscious of the variegated colours, so that to him the outline of the
>   building may be almost unaffected by the camouflage. In the [Ishihara
>   test for colourblindness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_perception_test), certain of the cards actually use this
>   principle; a faint blue figure is printed on a background of highly
>   coloured dots of various hues. To the normal observer the blue figure
>   is lost against the background, but the colour-blind person may spot
>   it. Again, in the [protanopic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protanopia#Dichromacy) and protanomalous type of defect, reds
>   and yellows appear darker than usual, and with certain colouring of
>   building and background this could lead to an enhanced contrast and so
>   give the colour-blind person his advantage.

The following are extracts taken from a [BBC article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/health/4498734.stm):

> The Cambridge team tested this idea by asking deuteranomalous and
>   "colour-normal" individuals to report whether they were able to
>   distinguish between pairs of colours that were theoretically predicted
>   to look different to people with deuteranomalous colour blindness, but
>   the same to those with normal colour vision.
>
> The researchers duly found some colour pairs were only seen to be
>   different by [deuteranomalous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness#By_cause) individuals.
>
> In fact, the researchers found people with deuteranomalous colour
>   blindness gave large difference ratings to pairs of colours which
>   appeared indistinguishable to others.
>
> The researchers, led by Dr John Mollon, said: "The present findings
>   recall reports from the Second World War, which **suggested that 'colour
>   blind' observers might be superior in penetrating camouflage.**"

For more information visit:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness
- http://www.archimedes-lab.org/colorblindnesstest.html
- http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/3037/is-colorblindness-an-evolutionary-advantage